# AWS - creating elastic beanstalk application without an EIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-ip

I've spent the whole morning trying to create an elastic beanstalk application without associating it to an EIP. Amazon has a limit of 5 EIPs so I want to just create an instance and then do a CNAME record to the .elasticbeanstalk.com.

However, this does not seem to work, even though I unchecked "create public IP" and removed "Auto assign IP" in all my VPC subnets, it still creates the EIP.

If I create the ELB instance, gives it the EIP, then removes the EIP, the whole instance just becomes stale and unreachable.

Does anybody have any experience with this and how do you solve it?

Thanks,

Johan

Comment: Why not ask for more EIPs? its not a hard limit and Amazon responds pretty quickly for these requests.

Comment: Also, how are you adding EIP to ELB? thought its not possible.

Comment: When you create your EB environment select load balanced and not single instance.

Comment: @RakeshBollampally it's a default config. Also a load balancer costs more.